# Doppler Effect in a video

Tags: doppler-effect

Suppose I record a video of a vehicle moving towards me while blowing its horn, and then play the video on, say 2x. Will the doppler shift differ from when I recorded the video in the first place? This question-https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/473806/speed-of-a-video-and-doppler-effect is somewhat similar, but I can't find my question being answered here.

Comment: would you know what happens with you speech in that case? the same happens to any sound you play at double speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all sound frequencies recorded in your video will double in pitch by 2x, and the duration of the doppler sweep itself will be cut in half.

Comment: @honeste_vivere How does it not answer the question?

Comment: @BioPhysicist - I had initially thought it was just a comment-worthy post, not an actual answer but have removed my criticism after looking at it more.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Comment-worthy posts are posts that either 1) Ask for clarifications from the OP or 2) Offer suggestions as to how to improve the OP's post. It is a common misconception among users here that comments should be used to post short "snap shot answers". Even if it is it a short answer, it should be an answer, not a comment. As long as the post addresses the question, then it is an answer (of course it could still be a poor-quality answer, but an answer nonetheless).

Comment: @BioPhysicist - Fair point and duly noted, thanks.